# Python - urllib.request and flask

Tags: python, url, post, flask, request

I have this `P2P` python code, and I am trying to send a `POST` request from it to `flask`:

On my `P2P` side I have:

```
...

for reply in con:
    jsonData = json.loads(reply)
    print(jsonData)
    print(type(jsonData) is dict, tuple)
    data = urlencode(jsonData)
    print(data + " : urlencode")
    data = data.encode()
    print(data.__class__)
    req = urllib.request.Request("http://0.0.0.0:5000/validate", data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    #res = response.read()
    print(response.read().decode('utf8') + " : response in alice")
```

For my `flask` code I have:

```
@app.route('/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate():

    print(request.args)
```

request args is always output as:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

The output for the `P2P` side is:

```
{'index': 2043, 'message': 'New Block Forged', 'previous_hash': 'fa4a49cd092869db788490e79a933e7a45107ce513523500e5cd9c85e25426de', 'proof': 168158, 'transactions': [{'amount': 1, 'recipient': '6760d061731c493e94897164c2362476', 'sender': '0'}]}
True <class 'tuple'>
index=2043&message=New+Block+Forged&previous_hash=fa4a49cd092869db788490e79a933e7a45107ce513523500e5cd9c85e25426de&proof=168158&transactions=%5B%7B%27amount%27%3A+1%2C+%27recipient%27%3A+%276760d061731c493e94897164c2362476%27%2C+%27sender%27%3A+%270%27%7D%5D : urlencode
<class 'bytes'>
{
  "add": true
}
 : response in alice
```

As you can see, the `data` for `urllib.request.urlopen` looks correct. Why isn't it getting through to the flask side?

Comment: Why don't you try the requests module? It's easier to comprehend.

Comment: I ended up using json which i prefer...not really an answer to this question so ill leave it open

Comment: Friend I am talking about the urllib module. Try sending the HTTP request using the requests module. It is easier to understand. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the `POST` request to `validate` endpoint. And request.args is only return the url querystring. So the real data will be available in `request.form`.

**Answer**

Please make the `GET` request... so `data` will be available in `request.args`

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(json_data)

url = 'http://localhost:5000?{}'.format(data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    pass
```

Comment: ah yes...this should be a get request...the request module looks cool too, definitely looks easier thanks